# Bootstrap 4: col same size as right col & image fill col

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

In my left `col` I have an `<img>`and in my right `col` I have some text. I want the left `col` to have the same height as the right `col`. Then I want the `<img>`to fill the left `col`. Seems simple but I couldn't do it. this is my current code:

```
                <div class="row">
                <div class="col-6 h-100">
                    <img class="img-fluid" src="@/assets/images/employee4.jpg">
                </div>
                <div class="col-6">
                    <h1 class="heading">HERREN</h1>
                    <hr>
                    <div class="row">
                        <h2 class="serivce">SCNHEIDEN</h2>
                        <h2 class="price float-right">18€</h2>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <h2 class="serivce">SCNHEIDEN</h2>
                        <h2 class="price float-right">18€</h2>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <h2 class="serivce">SCNHEIDEN</h2>
                        <h2 class="price float-right">18€</h2>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <h2 class="serivce">SCNHEIDEN</h2>
                        <h2 class="price float-right">18€</h2>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <h2 class="serivce">SCNHEIDEN</h2>
                        <h2 class="price float-right">18€</h2>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <h2 class="serivce">SCNHEIDEN</h2>
                        <h2 class="price float-right">18€</h2>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

It looks like this:
[image]

As You see the left `col` has the height of the right `col` and not the other way around and the image does not fill the `col``

Any Idea?

Comment: Have you tried adding the css of max-height to the image? Or you can write JS to capture the height of the right div and add that as height of the left one

Comment: What exactly do you mean by adding max-height? Should I set max-height to the exact value of the right `col`? I probably could use JS but I thought it would be possible without...

Comment: The question isn't clear. Do you want the image to "shrink" to the height of the  text on the right, or do you want to expand to the text to the height of the image. What size is the image?

Comment: I want the left `col` with the image to "shrik" to the height of the `col` with the text. The Image as the size 400x400

Answer (score 0):

set that image as a background image of the left col

CSS code

```
#leftcol {
background-image:url("image url");
background-size:cover;

}
```